# rxjs6 ActivatedRoute subscribe to observable

Tags: angular, rxjs6

in app.component I need to perform an action based on the ActivatedRoute. 
using: Angular6, rxjs6 (with it's new syntax)

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

....

constructor (private route:ActivatedRoute){
  const url: Observable<string> =route.url.pipe(map(segments=>segments.join('')));

}
```

the intent is to show/hide something based on changes in the activated route.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to the route like any normal observables, then put your logic inside the subscribe.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

....

constructor (private router: Router) {
  this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      console.log(event);
  });
}
```

[Docs](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#!#events-anchor)

Comment: I may be doing it wrong.  Did it in the constructor, it only runs once.  i need to retrieve for each change:
route.url.subscribe(data=>console.log(data);})
returns it only the first time

Comment: Modified the answer

Comment: looks pretty good, unsure how to isolate this to NavigationEnd though.  the event doesn't define that in a name.